# Split homepage to show 5 posts per page

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I split my homepage which shows posts's excerpts into various pages, showing only 5 excerpts per page and having a link to show older posts?
Like this:
[image]

Comment: I tried to search google, but didn't find the answer, so I'm asking here. I know it seems stupid, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to look into [Pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination)
Your script would have a work flow similar to this

```
<?php
$totalpost = 100;
$currentpost = 0;
$pagelimit = 5;
$current_page = 0;
$current_page_count = 0;
$totalpages = $totalpost / $pagelimit;
while($currentpost < $totalpost){
    $current_page_count = 0;
    while($current_page_count < $pagelimit){
        echo " $currentpost ";
        $currentpost++;
        $current_page_count++;
    }

    echo " <br> page $current_page <br>";
    $current_page++;
}
?>
```